# How to ask to be relocated for internship

Tags: internship, relocation

I recently received an internship offer from a major bank for software development. I'm very excited to have the opportunity to work for them. HR called me this Friday to discuss the details of the offer. Unfortunately, my cell phone was about to die so I have decided to call them back on Monday.

The problem is that one of the internship locations is in a city I do not want to stay in for the summer. I interviewed at one of the satellite offices in the city I go to college in. It's a great city, but I would really like to intern at their headquarters in New York City. I am considering moving to NYC after I graduate so it would be great to experience the city for a summer.

How do I mention to HR how I want to relocate? I do not want to seem unappreciative because I assume they would want me to do the internship in the city I interviewed in. I was thinking of mentioning how I would like to be closer to family (I live in Boston), but thought that would sound weird. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3):

And they probably assume that you want to intern in the city they interviewed you in. Just ask. Worst case, they say no. I don't think you should make up an excuse. I think you should just say that you are considering moving to NYC after graduation. Aka the truth.

Comment: And don't forget that interning in one city doesn't mean you can't ask to be transferred if and when you start a permanent job.